# TestNG tests are using the parameter of one test instead of their own

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng, browserstack

I'm using TestNG with parameters and it works fine for one test. But as soon as I add another test, the parameters start messing up. Instead of using their own parameters as defined in the xml file, they only use the parameter of one test.

```html
<suite name="Test suite" >
 <parameter name="key" value="value_1"/>
 <test name="Test1" > 
  <classes>
   <class name="package.Test" >
    <methods>
     <include name="method1" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <parameter name="key" value="value_2"/>
 <test name="Test2" > 
  <classes>
   <class name="package.Test" >
    <methods>
     <include name="method1" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 </suite>
```

For example on this file, both Test1 and Test2 use `key` with value `value_1`.
Here's how I call the parameters in my setup (I use @BeforeMethod because we need it for BrowserStack)

```
    @Parameters(value={"key"})
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setup(String key) {
```

Is there a reason why this is happening? I can't find anyone else with the same issue

Comment: I am having the same problem. My 2nd test parameter is not reinitialized, no matter whether I put it within <test>, <method>, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute test in parallel I would recommend you to use BrowserStack Sample TestNg GitHub Repo as mentioned below. It worked fine for me.
https://github.com/browserstack/testng-appium-app-browserstack